# I am trying to SELECT this 3 columns shown in one column using the IF statement or the concatinate

Tags: mysql

Here is the data I want to convert into SQL

| Seetle_date(1st Column) | days_to_settle (2nd Column) | days_late (3rd Column) | Settle_Status (outcome = 1column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/8/2021 | 11 | 0 | Settle on Time |
| 11/5/2021 | 16 | 0 | <15 Days Late |
| 10/11/2020 | 31 | 1 | <30 Days Late |

I don't know what function need to do this;

CASE STAEMENT, GROUP BY,
ORDER BY

I Got this FORMULA in EXCEL to Understand what I want.

```
=IF(AND(B2-C2\<=15,B2-C2\>=0),"Settle on Time",IF(AND(B2-C2\<=30,B2-C2\>15),"\<15 Days Late","\<30 Days Late"))
```

I need to convert this in sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
    WHEN (B2 - C2 <= 15 AND B2 - C2 >= 0) THEN 'Settle on Time'
    WHEN (B2 - C2 <= 30 AND B2 - C2 > 15) THEN '<15 Days Late'
    ELSE '<30 Days Late'
END
```

This query uses the `CASE` statement to handle the conditional logic. The `WHEN` clauses define the conditions to be checked, and the expressions after the `THEN` keywords specify the values to be returned if the conditions are met. The `ELSE` clause provides a fallback value if none of the conditions are met.